# Popup blocking the gdrive authorization in chrome

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-drive-api

So, the problem is that popup blocking the window open even if it is done by a user action, click for example..

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
   client_id: this.client_id,
   scope: this.scopes,
   access_type: 'online',
   immediate: immediate
}, function(authResult) {
   console.log(authResult)
});
```

If i simply open the window on user click as here:

```
$('.some').click(funciton(){
    window.open(someurl)
})
```

it works fine, but if i did it throw the gdrive api(gapi.auth.authorize), this blocking anyway.

A must, I can not force users to off popap blocking.
I hope that anybody now how solved it :), thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Include an onload event in your call to client.js

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>`

Call gapi.auth.init from the onload function:

`function handleClientLoad() { window.setTimeout(gapi.auth.init,1); }`

In your authorize configuration set immediate: false.

Check that 1. is below 2. in the flow of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding the a reference 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

> gapi.auth.init(callback)
>   Initializes the authorization feature. Call this when the client loads to prevent popup blockers from blocking the auth window on gapi.auth.authorize calls.

ps: vote up requires 15 reputation .. so couldn't vote up Ben's answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Popups that don't originate from user events will get blocked depending on your browser's settings. You can try setting **immediate** to false:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
   client_id: this.client_id,
   scope: this.scopes,
   immediate: false
}, function(authResult) {
   console.log(authResult)
});
```

You can use this code to refresh the access token after you've already authorized the app.

Comment: In my example variable "immediate" already contains false, popap already pops but blocking. gapi.auth.authorize calls on click event, but anyway blocking, that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The first call to gapi.auth.authorize can trigger popup blockers. The
>   best way to prevent this is to set up a user-triggered action that
>   calls gapi.auth.authorize with immediate: false parameter.

Quoted from the api documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#popup

Answer (score 0):

You only needs `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();` without button authorize permission. This disable the popup.

```
gapi.client.init({
     discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
     clientId: CLIENT_ID,
     scope: SCOPES
}).then(function () {    
     // Handle the initial sign-in state.
     gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
});
```