# Prevent Google picker popup from blocking by browser

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I have implemented Google Picker in my website using javascript. But Whenever a button to initialize picker is pressed, it gets blocked by browser.

I have searched and tried few solutions here like:

1. Adding `client.js` instead of `api.js`
2. Setting `'immediate' = false;`

But they are not working for me. Please help !

Comment: Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125804/), you need to call [`gapi.auth.init`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthinit) which initializes the authorization feature. Call this when the client loads to prevent popup blockers from blocking the auth window on `gapi.auth.authorize` calls. Here's also an [example](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054) suggested by this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/gL_rUTgE-Tg) that does not get blocked by popup blocker.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this, if the popup is fired from  click event then browsers will not block it, so the main idea is to initiate once and afterward trigger the picker creation directly by the click event.

To achieve this you can follow these steps:

1. Use `client` instead of `auth2`
2. Initialize `client`
3. `onckick` event must trigger the `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` once, afterward it must trigger `google.picker.PickerBuilder()`

[For more information you can see my GooglePicker wrapper class - gist](https://gist.github.com/mudafar/276db92a49cb21c5852db875643dbdc9)

Or:

```
    var GoogleAuth;
    var oathToken;
    gapi.load('client', function () {
    gapi.client.init({client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID", scope: "MY_SCOPE"}).then(function () {
        GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        });
    });


    function pick() {
        if (!oathToken) {
            GoogleAuth.signIn().then(function () {
                const user = this.GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
                oathToken = user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
            });
        } else {
            const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                .setOAuthToken(oathToken)
                .setDeveloperKey("MY_DEVELOPER_KEY")
                .setCallback((data) => myCallBack(data)).build();

            picker.setVisible(true)
            }
    }

    function myCallBack(data) {
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            const docs = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
            const url = docs[0][google.picker.Document.URL];
            const name = docs[0][google.picker.Document.NAME];

            console.log("Picked file's name: ", name);
            console.log("Picked file's url: ", url);
            // etc...
        }
    }
```