# detect error: "popup_blocked_by_browser" for google auth2 in javascript

Tags: google-app-engine, popup, popup-blocker

After lot of googling didn't find solution how to catch error of window popup blocker for google auth2

getting an error in console error: "popup_blocked_by_browser".
all I want is to do is tell user that pop up should be enabled for auth.

samples using window.open() are not good, since they open useless window.
As I see a lot of people searching for this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!! 
signIn() method uses JS Promise. So code can be used is:

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(function(){}, function(error){ if (error) alert('please allow popup for this app')})
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: This is not the answer. For those looking for the reason and the real answer to this issue, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657983/popup-blocking-the-gdrive-authorization-in-chrome

Comment: sorry, but didnt find answer here.

Answer (score 11):

Was having same problem. Seems browser(s) (or at least chrome) will block any "window.open" call which it was invoked not as part of a user interaction.

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set#9514875) for a deeper explanation.

__

I used to have this next code inside click event listener:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    fetch_basic_profile: true,
    scope: 'profile'
  });
  auth2.signIn()
    .then(function() {
      var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
      ... 
    })
    .catch(function(err) { ... });
});
```

Note the asynchronous way of loading 'auth2', which is how google docu says.

I changed it to:

```
// way earlier, before click event can happen
// we call the gapi.load method.
gapi.load('auth2', function() {});
```

Then, inside click event handler, we can do:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    fetch_basic_profile: true,
    scope: 'profile'
  });
  auth2.signIn()
    .then(function() { ... })
    .catch(function(err) { ... });
```

... so browser does not block google login popup

Comment: I wish the google docs would just say which methods are async or sync. Totally not obvious that `gapi.auth2.init` is sync... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `gapi.auth2.init` is *async*. It returns a `Promise`-like `GoogleAuth` object, as per docs: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauth2initparams

Comment: Alternatively, add the `gapi.load()` part to the script tag
`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer onload="gapi.load('auth2');"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor (service) or ngOnInit (for component) do the following:

```
 googleAuthService.getAuth().subscribe(
  (auth) => {
    this.googleAuth = auth;
  });
```

Then, in your login function, call:

```
    this.googleAuth.signIn()
  .then((user) => {
      this.signInSuccessHandler(user as GoogleUser);
    },
    (error) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Now you need to use **Firebase auth**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

### Answer:

For me I changed init method to have a **callback function** (empty one)... Here's how:

**Wrong** (popup blocked by browser) (no call back function):

```
.init({ client_id: main.clientId })
```

**Correct** working like charm:

```
.init({ client_id: main.clientId, () => { } })
```

Comment: @MarcoA.Braghim I updated the answer with firebase solution

Comment: Guess you miss something. This post is about this error with Web Browser...